# Knockout.js input type date data binding in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, knockout.js

I'm struggling to set a value on the input of `type="date"` in google chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/gNv7H/

```
<input data-bind="value: dateString" type="date"></input>

var viewModel = {
    someDate: new Date(parseInt("/Date(1367708400000)/".substr(6)))
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

My date will come from JSON data but first I need to find out which format does it need to be in for Chrome's date picker to recognize the binding. Would I have to do it with jQuery selector and set `.val()` on the field? Seems daft...

Edit: according to [this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome), the date format to set the value on Google date input must always be `"yyyy-mm-dd"`. Which is a pitty, because we're using jQuery date picker for all browsers where there's no native date pickers exist.

Comment: Note that according to the [W3 standard draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) this won't be chrome specific but every browser will/should implement like this: "yyyy-mm-dd" the date format. By the why you can configure the jQuery date picker to use this format so I don't see your problem...

Comment: date format displayed is going to be tenant specific. E.g. mm/dd/yyyy for US, mm.dd.yyyy for Russia, dd/mm/yyyy for UK etc. At the source however, it'll always be JSON date format.

Comment: So you can have your date in whatever format in the model/source. Then you need to convert it to  "yyyy-mm-dd" when setting the value of your inputs. And you can setup the jQuery to use this "yyyy-mm-dd" format to store the data. And you need to setup jQuery  and also the chrome native datepicker to display it in any target format. So you will have eventually three formatting: the source, the format for the input, the format for the display. I don't see a problem here this is how these the thing are working when you have to deal with dates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to correctly format your `value` as described in the [W3C working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html):

> A valid full-date as defined in **[RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)**, with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0.

> Example:
> 1996-12-19

So the following should work:

```
var viewModel = {    
    dateString: ko.observable('2002-02-02')
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQPjk/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you give me any idea about how to html5 datepicker (input type "date") with knockout.js without using computed variables? like it is done here: http://screencast.com/t/pMtuSV6mxUf